# Общий доступ к файлам и каталогам

Tags: linux, chmod, chown

Вводные: ОС - Linux Общий каталог `USERSHARE` и несколько пользователей, входящих в одну группу `USERGROUP`. Пользователь vasya создал файл `/USERSHARE/file.txt`. Права файлу наследуются от каталога `/USERSHARE`, т.е. владелец `user`, группа `USERGROUP` и права доступа к файлу 660. Есть пользователь `sasha`, который открыл файл `/USERSHARE/file.txt` и отредактировал его. Права доступа к файлу остались неизменными, т.е. владелец `user`, группа `USERGROUP` и права доступа к файлу 660.

Как настроить права доступа к файлу и каталогу так, чтобы после редактирования файла пользователем sasha в атрибутах файла сменялся владелец.

Answer (score 1):

Владельца файла может назначить только root

```
chown sasha /USERSHARE/file.txt
```

Comment: А вот и нет, любой sudoer может.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё бы чуть побольше данных (чем именно организован общий ресурс - самба или какой-то изврат с `NFS`, кусочек конфигурации посмотреть) и я бы помог вам справиться с задачей, а пока могу только посоветовать обратить внимание на `umask`. А вообще-то так (чтобы после редактирования пользователем, владелец файла менялся на последнего редактора), наверное, обычными средствами нельзя, но вот написать простейший скриптик, который при запуске редактора будет менять владельца в принципе реально. Вопрос ещё интересен? просто сейчас немного занят, код сочинять (и тестировать - ну не выложить же не протестированный код? -) времени нет